# chunked http encoding with compression using a java library

Tags: java, http

I have read quite a few posts on stack overflow and it seems gzip can compress streams(ie. I am assuming they mean compress X bytes of the stream at a time).  What I don't get is how to do this properly so browsers will decompress it?  Let's say I have a 1GB file people need to download and I don't want to bring that all into memory at the same time.  How do I compress each chunk and send it on?

closely related question [gzip compression of chunked encoding response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280633/gzip-compression-of-chunked-encoding-response)

though java code would be great if anyone knows of any.  I looked at old playframework 1.2.x code but that doesn't appear to do any compression on writing out chunks :(.

thanks,
Dean