# streaming very large file and http chunking

Tags: http

I keep reading stuff like this

[gzip compression of chunked encoding response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280633/gzip-compression-of-chunked-encoding-response)

Is there a way to work around this limitation of needing ALL of the content in-memory at once (which significantly impacts my RAM).  I am wondering if one of the streaming compression protocols could be used?

I really wonder for browsers for uploading and downloading if they really put the whole thing in memory for a very very large file(I hope they don't).  At the same time, I am thinking for large files, this just doesn't work too well yet.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: gzip allows streaming, so no, you don't need the whole contents in memory.